# Instantiating an Interface

Tags: java, interface

Say i have an interface `I` with method `doIt();`

Now i have a class `C` that implements `I` and hence provides the implementation for `doIt();`

For the following code in Class `Hello`

```
public class Hello{
    I i = new I();
    i.doIt();
}
```

1.) Now where does it take the implementation of doIt() from?

2.) What if there was another class `HelloWorld` implementing `I` too with a different iplementation for the `doIt()` function. Then which implementation would it have taken?

Comment: have you tried compiling this.... the compiler may have something to tell you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try compiling this stuff. You can only instantiate a `Class` which implements the `Interface` and not the `Interface` directly.

An `Interface` is just like a contract which a `Class` agrees to when it `implements` it; and within the agreement of the `Interface`, `Class` provides the implementation of it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot instantiate an interface. You can only instantiate a concrete class. The implementation of `doIt()` is the one defined in the concrete class that was instantiated. If that class doesn't provide an implementation, it gets inherited from a superclass.

As a sidenote, in your code example, you have code in a class that is not contained within a method or static block. This is not legal. You must enclose code in a method or static block.

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces cannot be instantiated. The code you have posted *should* not compile. What you can do is something like so: `I c = new C();`. This will also make sure that the appropriate implementation of `doIt()` will me called.

Refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) Oracle tutorial for more information on `Interfaces`.

Answer (score 2):

This will never work

```
public class Hello{
    I i = new I(); // I is an interface, can't be instantiated
    i.doIt();
}
```

I think you want...

```
public class A implements I {
    public void doIt() {

        System.out.println("A did it");

    }
}
public class B implements I {
    public void doIt() {

        System.out.println("B did it");

    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        I i = new A();
        i.doIt();
        i = new B();
        i.doIt();
    }
}
```

This will output

```
A did it
B did it
```

Answer (score 1):

Only way around to instantiate interface is to add anonymous inner type specific to your implementation. Though it looks like a bad design sometimes it's useful. cheers.

```
    II i = new II() {

        @Override
        public void doit() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no implemenatation and your code will not compile. Try creating a simple working example and you will understand. BTW the syntax is wrong anyway: if I is an interface, you need opening curly braces to create an anonymous class implementing the interface:

```
I i = new I() { public void doIt() {} };
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `I i = new I();` is **incorrect** as `I` is an `interface` and interface cannot be **instantiated** , if you have to do it then this should be

```
I i = new I(){
   public returntype doIt(){
    ...
   }
};
```

now the above implementation is known as **Anonymous Inner Classes** [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)